# How do I configure IIS Express to run with VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, iis-express

I have the IIS Express Beta downloaded and installed on WinXP.  I don't have VS2010.

How do I configure VS2008 to launch IIS Express Beta when debugging/running a site?

Comment: Right click on your web project and open up properties.  On the 'Web' tab, can you choose 'Use Local IIS Web Server'?

Comment: No. I have the new IIS Express, not IIS.  I can't even open the project without editing the xml of the csproj file to set UseIIS to false.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following seems to work for IIS Express launching from the command line:

1. Open the `Properties` for the web site
2. Select `Start Options`
3. Under Start Action select `Start External Program`, put the path to `iisexpress.exe` (`C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe`)
4. Command Line Arguments: /path:{path to the project solution} /clr:3.5
5. Under `Server`, select `Use Custom Server`
6. Base Url: `http://localhost:8080/` (the default for IIS Express, you can change this with command line arguments)
7. **Important!** Uncheck everything under `Debuggers` otherwise you'll get an error "Unable to start debugging on the web server..."

Information on launching using a config file can be found at this site: [Debug Your .NET Web Project With IIS Express [Tips & Tricks]](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2010/7/11/debug-your-net-web-project-with-iis-express-t.aspx).  This is VS2010 specific but I suspect the same will work for 2008.

Comment: Two comments: 1. Remember to put your path in quotation marks if it contains spaces 2. Put the path to the project containing the webpage, not the solution

Comment: Note that this requires Service Pack 1 of Visual Studio 2008.  Otherwise the "Use Custom Web Server" option is not available.

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to do the same however as there will be [no direct vs2008 integration for iis express](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx#7548551) (they've only just added it to the vs2010 sp1 beta) to use it for testing/development you need to do the following.

1. Start a website in iisexpress using the following command line ([iisexpress command line parameters](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/870/running-iis-express-from-the-command-line/)), change the $(ProjectDir) to be what you need it to be.

   "%programfiles%/iis express/iisexpress.exe" /path:$(ProjectDir) /port:4326 /clr:v2.0
2. Attach the Visual Studio debugger to the iisexpress.exe process
3. Browse to http://localhost:4326 or right click the iisexpress systray icon and select your site

Note: I've tried to hook this up as a post-build event in visual studio but if you use the cmd above then vs2008 hangs until iisexpress terminates. 
I've also tried using this with `start /b` or placing the cmd in a batch file and trying to start that but neither option works.

Thanks

Keith